# Correctly Format JSON Output in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am retrieving the name of an employee from one API and need to format some JSON to transmit it over an outgoing api.  I need my output to look like this.

```
A {"employees":[{"name":"Charles Johnson"}]}
```

Right now my output looks like this:

```
B {"employees":"[{\"name\":\"Robert Johnson\"}]"}
```

based on the following code:

```
$employee = "Robert Johnson";//string retrieved from API
$return = json_encode(array(array('name'=>$employee)));

echo json_encode(array('employees'=>$return));
```

How can I convert B so it looks like A. Note I would prefer not to alter the last line (echo...) as it is used for various other things as well.  'd like to prep $return so that it echoes out in the form of A.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json encode is required only once after preparing all the data. Please find the below code
hope it will help you.

```
$employee = "Robert Johnson";//string retrieved from API
$return =array(array('name'=>$employee));

echo json_encode(array('employees'=>$return));
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

You encode JSON data twice so just do it once, in last line that outputs it.

Comment: What would prior line be? If i do $str2 = "value:".$employee;
$return = array($str2); then I get {"employees":["value:Robert Johnson"]}. Should I be manually inserting quote marks?